# Dynamic LINQ Query System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

> System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'No property or field 'Name' exists in type 'IEnumerable`1''

How to use Complex object to do order by in Dynamic linq query! I am using  System.Linq.Dynamic.Core for dynamic linq query.

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

using (var context = new SchoolContext())
{
    var list = context.Courses.Include("Students").AsQueryable();
    var result = list.OrderBy("Students.Name").ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + item.Name );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Added code. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is trying to run an order by on a list.

If you want the students ordered by name in a course try the following

```
var list = context.Courses.Include(c => c.Students).AsQueryable();
var result = list.Select(course => 
   new Course { 
      Id = course.Id, 
      Name = course.Name, 
      Students = course.Students.OrderBy(s => s.Name) 
   }).ToList();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach(var student in item.Students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + student.Name );
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use Complex object to do order by in Dynamic linq query! I am using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core for dynamic linq query.